# How can I check .NET framework 4.5 prerequestics in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, .net-framework-version

I'd like to validate both .NET framework 4.0 and 4.5 should be installed at server before proceeding a installation. Hence I used the following snippet, but I don't know about 4.5 validattion, which was not listed in the link [Reference](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm)

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
    <Condition Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
    </Condition>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `NETFRAMEWORK45` property can be used the same as the `NETFRAMEWORK40FULL`. Note there is no "client" or "full" framework for The .NET Framework v4.5. There is just one.  So the following code should do what you want:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>

<Condition Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
<Condition Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>
```

Note that .NET Framework v4.5 is an in place upgrade of .NET Framework 4.0 so checking for both could get you into a situation where you'll never satisfy both conditions. You might want to just check that .NET Framework v4.0 *or* .NET Framework v4.5 is installed. That condition would look more like:

```
<Condition Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full or 4.5 package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Thanks rob. If you update this information on the Online  Reference will helpful everyone to find out easily.